# @Stereotype annotation in Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, annotations

What's the purpose of `@Stereotype` annotation in Java EE?

I saw the documentation, but could not get much from it. Can someone point out with the help of an clear example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the [Java EE API for Stereotype](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/inject/Stereotype.html), which explains it. It is used in architecture to name reoccurring patterns. One example is the predefined [Model](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/inject/Model.html) annotation.

Answer (score 3):

Sterotypes are "roles" of software architectural components. For example a Service class or a Repository bean.

The `@Sterotype` annotation is a [meta annotation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Annotations/Meta-Annotations) and it is used to annotate annotation "classes" to state that the particular annotation is a stereotype definition.

```
@Stereotype 
@Target(TYPE) 
@Retention(RUNTIME) 
public @interface Action {}
```

This example from the documentation shows how the annotation `Action` is annotated with `@Sterotype`. You could then annotate classes with `@Action` to make use of the Action stereotype.